# Why am I getting subscript out of range error when trying to redim?

Tags: vba, ms-access

I'm trying to make a dynamic array that adds units in a loop.
every time I try to redim and add a unit, I get the following error:

*Subscript out of range*

My code:

```
dim arr()
strSql = "SELECT item from dupEmail"
    Set rs = CurrentDb.OpenRecordset(strSql)
    rs.MoveFirst
    ReDim arr(0)
    Do While Not rs.EOF
        arr(UBound(arr, 1)) = rs.Fields(0)
        ReDim Preserve arr(1, UBound(arr, 1) + 1)
        rs.MoveNext
    Loop
```

I tried `ReDim Preserve arr(0, UBound(arr, 0) + 1)` but that didn't work either.

Comment: On which line does the error occur? And why do you want to redim anyways? Find the number of entries in your recordset before looping through and set the length of your array beforehand.

Comment: Why not just use the recordset?  Have you tried Redim preserve arr(ubound(arr)+1)

Comment: The error occurs on the redim line. Thanks for the tip but I gotta do it this way. Keep in mind that this is a simplification of my code.

Comment: @Nathan_Sav, Yes. Still get the same error.

Comment: Isn't it a single index array and trying to redim it to be multi-dimensional array?

Comment: @smozgur, Well then how would I do it? It is indeed not a multidimensional array.

Comment: Seems like you are looping over the recordset to add an item to your array on each instance, but you could just use `arr  = rs.GetRows` to get the entire recordset as a 2d array?

Comment: @smozgur, Thanks, that was it. You should post it as the answer.

Comment: @MJH: I already did that code sample was not good in the comment area. Glad to hear it helps.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
ReDim arr(a, b)
```

is the same as

```
ReDim arr(0 To a, 0 To b)
```

What you want is

```
ReDim arr(a To b)
```

In your case you Dim arr as a one-dimensional array of length 1 with `ReDim arr(0)`. Then you try to ReDim it as a two-dimensional array. If you dont use `Preserve` that works just fine but with `Preserve` it doesn't know where to put the old value (I think) and throws an error.

So to fix your problem, replace `ReDim Preserve arr(1, UBound(arr, 1) + 1)` with `ReDim Preserve arr(1 To UBound(arr, 1) + 1)` but there are other preferable ideas mentioned in the comments. Keep in mind that "redimming" can be time consuming. In the worst case, the program has to allocate new (larger) memory and copy everything from the old location in every iteration. It likely won't be noticeable anyway but it's still better practice to allocate the whole array before the loop.

edit: Oh didn't notice that it was already mentioned in the comments.

edit2: In a non-representative test, redimming within the loop took about 6 times as long as redimming beforehand.

Answer (score 2):

I think easier to post suggested code: comment doesn't show all: You already Redim at 0 index, so what you need is to increment for each record. It will create one unnecessary at the end, remove it.

```
dim arr()
strSql = "SELECT item from dupEmail"

Set rs = CurrentDb.OpenRecordset(strSql)
rs.MoveFirst
ReDim arr(0)
Do While Not rs.EOF
    arr(UBound(arr)) = rs.Fields(0)
    ReDim Preserve arr(UBound(arr) + 1)
    rs.MoveNext
Loop
ReDim Preserve arr(UBound(arr) - 1)
```

Or simply redim for all records by using rs.RecordCount instead Redim(0) and avoid Redim in the loop. You need a counter of course.